# How to format initial value for TextFormField using formatter in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a text field in which users enter sums. And I want these sums to be formatted by thousands (for example `500 000`). I found a formatter that can do that. The problem is that this formatter is not called, when initial value is set in controller. As a result text is not formatted until user modifies it.

For example, if we set initial value as `500000` then text field shows `500000` instead of
`500 000` until user modifies this value.

This is my code:

```
class ThousandTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  static const separator = ','; // Change this to '.' for other locales

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    // Short-circuit if the new value is empty
    if (newValue.text.length == 0) {
      return newValue.copyWith(text: '');
    }

    // Handle "deletion" of separator character
    String oldValueText = oldValue.text.replaceAll(separator, '');
    String newValueText = newValue.text.replaceAll(separator, '');

    if (oldValue.text.endsWith(separator) &&
        oldValue.text.length == newValue.text.length + 1) {
      newValueText = newValueText.substring(0, newValueText.length - 1);
    }

    // Only process if the old value and new value are different
    if (oldValueText != newValueText) {
      int selectionIndex =
          newValue.text.length - newValue.selection.extentOffset;
      final chars = newValueText.split('');

      String newString = '';
      for (int i = chars.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ((chars.length - 1 - i) % 3 == 0 && i != chars.length - 1)
          newString = separator + newString;
        newString = chars[i] + newString;
      }

      return TextEditingValue(
        text: newString.toString(),
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
          offset: newString.length - selectionIndex,
        ),
      );
    }

    // If the new value and old value are the same, just return as-is
    return newValue;
  }
}

...

var sumController = TextEditingController(text: 500000.toString());//setting initial value
...
TextFormField(
  inputFormatters: [ThousandTextInputFormatter()],
  controller: sumController,
)
```

Could anyone say how to format initial value using formatter, if it is possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made it work this way:

```
sumController.value = ThousandTextInputFormatter()    
  .formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue.empty, TextEditingValue(text: 500000.toString()));
```

Comment: Nice. Would be helpful if you can include the ThousandTextInput class too

Comment: @KaushikChandru Thank you. I included formatter code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a value to the textController instead of setting _textController.text

```
_textEditingController.value = TextEditingValue(text: "500000");
```

**EDIT**

```
myTextEditingController.value.copyWith(
  text: "5000000",
  selection: TextSelection(
    baseOffset: "5000000".length,
    extentOffset: "5000000.length
  )
)
```

Comment: No, it didn't help.

Comment: I've checked your new solution, but unfortunately it doesn't work either.